# How to send/receive a HTTP request in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How to send/receive a HTTP request (it is good to give me a link)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx

Do you know what i typed into Google?

"c# .net send web request"

And this was the first result.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest option is the [System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class, but that isn't always powerful enough to do what you need.